# how to correctly set up $PATH environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

#### I am installing Yarn. In guide, it asks to set up PATH environment variable.

[image]

#### But in my .profile, it already has rvm PATH.

[image]

#### How to set up PATH correctly???

1. Just paste, `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin"`, at the end of the file???
2. Change, `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"` into `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$HOME/.yarn/bin"`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the line `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin"` to the **end** of your `.profile` file. I.e. the final result should look like this

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to go with your second option and use:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin`

Otherwise, your $PATH variable will no longer reference the .rvm directory, leading to issues with your Ruby installation.

Alternatively, you can add it below the current line such as:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.yarn/bin`

This has the same effect.